# PythonのHTTP通信リダイレクトについて

Tags: python, go, http, python3

Go言語のこのコードと同じことをPythonで書きたいです
PythonだとURLしか渡せないのでしょうか？
分かる方、どのように書けばいいのか教えてください！

```golang
http.Redirect(w, r, "/todos", 303)
```

Comment: Webサーバ側をPythonのどんなフレームワークで書いていますか。標準のCGIパッケージ? Django? Bottle? Flask?

Comment: ＞quiquiさま　コメント有難うございます。Flaskです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flaskなら `redirect('/todos', code=303)`でいいと思いますよ。

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect('/foo', code=303)


@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    response = make_response('redirected')
    response.headers['content-type'] = 'text/plain'
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8080)
```

これを動かして`http://localhost:8080/`にアクセスするとリダイレクトされます。

あるいは`redirect(url_for('foo'), code=303)`もありです。この例だと`foo`関数がコールされるようなurlを組み立てろ、という指示になります。

---

というか、GoLangの `http.Redirect(w, r, "/todos", 303)`だって、ここで指定している `"/todos"`はURLだと思うんですが。

---

> HTTPのボディ部分やヘッダー部分に‌​なにかを埋め込んだり、そういったカスタマ‌​イズは難しいでしょうか

できますが難しいです。難しいというのは「コードの動きを理解したりするのが難しい」ということです。

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.redirect
関数の`Redirect=`引数にカスタムのReponseクラスを指定できます。指定しない時にどうなるかは書いてあるとおりですが、そのクラスを使って
https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/utils.py#L373
というようにインスタンス化されています。このデフォルトのコンテンツを無視するようにすればいいです。

が。ちょっと調べても推奨のやり方みたいなものは見つかりませんでした。

ひとまず

```
from flask import Flask, Response, make_response, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)


class CustomRedirectResponse(Response):
    def __init__(self, response=None, status=None, headers=None, mimetype=None, content_type=None,
                 direct_passthrough=False):
        # 引数として与えられてくるresponseを無視して自分が出したいコンテンツを
        # 親クラスの初期化子の第1引数にセットしてしまう（他の引数はそのまま委譲）
        super().__init__('Custom Response...', status, headers, mimetype, content_type, direct_passthrough)

        # 独自ヘッダを追加したり
        self.headers['custom-header'] = 'customized'


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect('/foo', code=303, Response=CustomRedirectResponse)


@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    response = make_response('redirected')
    response.headers['content-type'] = 'text/plain'

    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8080)
```

みたいに書けばレスポンスをすげ替えられることは確認できました。

Comment: 不可能じゃなくて「必要がない」のです。
Goの方は呼び出し元から ResponseWriter と Request が渡されてきて、クライアントにレスポンスを返すところまでをやらないといけないので、Redirect に渡して「書き出してもらって」います。
Flaskは、クライアントにレスポンスを返すところは呼び出し元がやってくれるので、「こういうレスポンスを返して欲しい」というデータを返すだけでいいのです。

クライアントにレスポンスを返す主体が「ユーザが書いたコードから見た時の呼び出し元」なのか「ユーザ（が書いたコード）」なのかの違いです。

Comment: なるほど。丁寧に書いてくださってありがとうございます！呼び出し元の指定は要らないのですね。Pythonでいうリダイレクトで、HTTPのボディ部分やヘッダー部分になにかを埋め込んだり、そういったカスタマイズは難しいでしょうか